# paypal,sandbox not returning the post data in mobile browser

Tags: php, paypal, mobile-browser

I have integrated Paypal (sandbox) in my web application. It's working correctly in web browser, returning post and get data's in web browser, but not returning the post data's in mobile browsers.

I have checked chrome and ucbrowser.

Friends help me.

Comment: Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as a help to reword your question and to elaborate on the problem.

Comment: Did your issue got fixed? I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a standard WPS button you may wanted to add this line of code.

```
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
```

Try it out and see if that helps.